# Yes /N0 : Is $f$ is uniformly continious ?.

Tags: real-analysis

> Is    $f(x) = \cos x \sin^2x$ is uniformly contnious  on  $\mathbb{R}$ ?

My attempt : I thinks  No because

$\sin x \cong x $ now $f(x)$  will  become   $f(x)=  x^2 \cos x$

we know that $x^2$ is not uniformly contnious on $\mathbb{R}$

Is its true ?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean when you say $\sin(x)\cong x$? Because I don't think you're using that statement the way it's meant to be used.

Comment: i used my  logics  , i think i may be  wrong @Arthur sir

Comment: Continuous periodical function is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|f'(x)| \leq 3$ for all $x$ and MVT shows that $f$ is uniformly continuous.